# Tamaño de celdas?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Hola me podrian ayudar por favor, no estoy entendiendo porque pasa esto ya que todos estan configurados para tener el mismo tamaño pero como pueden observar en la imagen no lo hacen.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Correo Electronico</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="email" name="email" required class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Correo Electronico"><br>
    </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Tipo de Evento</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="text" name="tipo" required class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Tipo de Evento"><br>
    </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Frases</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="text" name="frases" required class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Frases"><br>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Tipo de Relleno</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="text" name="tipore" required class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Tipo de Relleno"><br>
    </div>
```

[image: Como pueden observar en la imagen]

Comment: Creo que el problema son tus div, creo que hay algunos que no estas cerrando, al menos en el codigo que muestras es asi.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, me paso de alto eso. Muchas gracias.

Comment: La pondré como respuesta para que quede la solución para los por si alguien necesita lo mismo, o como complemento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recuerda que los div son divisiones, por ende tanto el primer tag `<div>` como `</div>` son obligatorios, cerrando estos no tendrías problemas en el diseño.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Correo Electronico</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input type="email" name="email" required class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Correo Electronico"><br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Tipo de Evento</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input type="text" name="tipo" required class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Tipo de Evento"><br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Frases</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input type="text" name="frases" required class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Frases"><br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Tipo de Relleno</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input type="text" name="tipore" required class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Tipo de Relleno"><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Dejo referencias por si gustas leer.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/div